# Entity Framework With MySql Connectivity not working

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have been wandering around for this but couldn't find a single good article that would work. There are bits and peaces everywhere but not a complete code for this.

It's frustrating why Microsoft would make it so hard to connect EF with MySql whereas for SQL Server it takes only few mins.

Could anyone please make it easier and just illustrate in simple steps to create EF with MySql. I am only interested in the connection part otherwise i have been working in EF for couple of years. I know the rest. Here's the code and the related libraries.

```
Data Context Class 

   public ReservationDataContext() : base(@"server=localhost;port=3306;database =xxx;uid=xx;pwd=xx") { }

    partial void OnCreated();


    public ReservationDataContext(string connectionString): base(connectionString)
    {
        this.OnCreated();
    }



    public ReservationDataContext(string connection, MappingSource mappingSource) : 
        base(connection,mappingSource)
    {
        this.OnCreated();
    }


    public Table<Reservation> Reservations
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Reservation>();
        }
    }


 Entity Class: 
   [Table(Name = "reservations")]
public class Reservation
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public bool IsReserved { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Status { get; set; }
```

The dlls are as follows.

[dlls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsnPd.png)

I was getting errors where it was picking up sql server entity framework instead of mysql dll. So resolved that. Isn't giving any error on that but returns null and not fetching the data. Here's the code for that.

In Query Handler class.

```
private ReservationContext reservationContext;
    public QueryHandler()
    {

        reservationContext = new ReservationContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReservationDataContext"].ConnectionString);
    }


    public List<Reservation> GetAllReservations()
    {
        List<Reservation> resList = reservationContext.Reservations.ToList();

        return resList;
    }
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what your problem is? What have you tried and where are you failing? Are you using `MySql.Data` / `MySql.Data.Entity` nuget packages?
Please also read up on how to create a [mcve]

Comment: And what about the official documentation ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: Hi . Thanks for the quick reply . I have edited the question. Please take a look. Thanks.